# Xamarin.iOS async await method not working

Tags: c#, ios, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, async-await

I'm developing an iOS app in Xamarin in C#, I have a method, that must be called in  Asynchronous mode. I got [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/async_support_overview/) guideline, but it seems to be different from my needs.

I tried to do this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<UIImage>>();
            var imageUrls = new[] {
                "http://www.mySite/images/02.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/03.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/04.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/05.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/06.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/07.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/08.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/09.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/10.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/11.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/12.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/3.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/14.jpg",
                "http://www.mySite/images/15.jpg"

            };
    foreach (var imageUrl in imageUrls)
            {
                var task = getImageFromUrl(imageUrl);
                tasks.Add(task);
            }
            var images = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

the called method is:

```
async Task<UIImage> getImageFromUrl(string uri)
    {
        using (var url = new NSUrl(uri))
        using (var data = NSData.FromUrl(url))
            return UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
    }
```

it runs synchronously, and shows me the following warning:

```
Warning CS1998: Async block lacks `await' operator and will run synchronously (CS1998)
```

What am I missing in my code? 
It seems that the getImageFromUrl() method misses an async property. Are there other way to load images from url asynchrously?

Comment: Please update your code to show the bits that need to be async (db access, network call, etc).

Comment: @Jason just edited....

Comment: none of those operations are async.  You can manually execute them in a different thread if you like, but they are not inherently async operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have shown in your example is not asynchronous. If you want to load all 6 images, you probably want to have something like this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<UIImage>>();
var imageUrls = new[] {"http://www.mySite/images/02.jpg", ... "http://www.mySite/images/09.jpg"};
foreach (var imageUrl in imageUrls) {
  var task = // invoke a method which loads an image asynchronously and returns a Task, but don't call await on this Task
  tasks.Add(task);
}
var images = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Also, the code that you have in `getImageFromUrl` does not invoke any asynchronous methods. You may consider using `HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync` to load data asynchronously and then create an Image from this byte array:

```
async Task<UIImage> getImageFromUrl(string uri)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    var imageBytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
    var image = // create image from imageBytes;
    return image;
}
```

Comment: i updated my post, but the issue is the same, where am i wrong in my code?

Comment: your code did not invoke any asynchronous operations, see my updated answer